# How can I handle check box using Button in Java?

Tags: java, android

I want to handle checkboxes using a button.
When I press on Check button I want to write if it's false or true and how can let the user check only 1 checkbox only from the choices?

```
      package com.example.android.qa;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void Question1(View v) {

         CheckBox Html = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Html);
         boolean hasHtml = Html.isChecked();

         CheckBox Css = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Css);
         boolean hasCss = Css.isChecked();


         CheckBox JavaScript = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Java_Script);
         boolean hasJavaScript = JavaScript.isChecked();

         String Answer1 = Question1Active("True", "False","False");

    }

    public String Question1Active(String Html, String Css, String JavaScript){

        String Answer1 = "\n" + getString(R.string.True) + Html;
        Answer1 = "\n" + getString(R.string.False) + Css;
        Answer1 = "\n" + getString(R.string.False) + JavaScript;
        return Answer1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `RadioButton` instead of `CheckBox`

Comment: What do you mean by "write"?

Comment: I mean it will display to the user the answer is true or false

Answer (score 0):

Use RadiGroup

If we check one radio button that belongs to a radio group, it automatically unchecks any previously checked radio button within the same group.

```
  <RadioGroup
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="90dp"
          android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
          android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
          android:weightSum="1"
          android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
          android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
          android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
          android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
          android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3">

          <RadioButton
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="55dp"
             android:text="Male"
             android:id="@+id/radioButton"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:checked="false"
             android:textSize="25dp" />

          <RadioButton
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Female"
             android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:checked="false"
             android:textSize="25dp"
             android:layout_weight="0.13" />
       </RadioGroup>
```

Your Java Code:

```
 radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup);
 firstRadioButton= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.firstRadioButton);      
 secondRadioButton= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.secondRadioButton);
```

// find which radio button is selected

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override           public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int
             checkedId) {
                            // find which radio button is selected
                            if(checkedId == R.id.firstRadioButton) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: firstRadioButton", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if(checkedId == R.id.secondRadioButton) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: SeconRadioButton", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                            });
```

Comment: What about the java code I am trying to display true or false text after I pressed on check button how can it work?

Comment: setOnCheckedChangeListener shows me an error (non-static method cannot be referenced from static context)